# Money is not being sent or received when using PayPal REST SDK and PayPal-Python-SDK

Tags: python, rest, paypal, payment

I've integrated the PayPal payment process in this following way using [PayPal-Python-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK).

1. Order is made on our website. At this point I know how much to charge the visitor.
2. I configure the `paypalrestsdk` module by passing `mode` argument as `live` (not `sandbox`), client ID and client secret for `live` settings.
3. I create a payment using `paypalrestsdk.Payment` to which I pass tons of parameters including `return_url`, `cancel_url`, `price`, `currency`, `quantity` and some others.
4. If the payment is created without errors, I get the `redirect_url` from the created payment.
5. User clicks the link which redirects him to the `redirect_url`, which is PayPal page where he fills in either his PayPal details or Credit Card details.
6. User pays the amount of money and is being redirected back to our site.
7. As a last step I check if there is a record in the DB with the payment ID that came in GET or POST parameters and if there is one in the DB, I'm marking it as `paid`.

Now, the problem is that the whole process works fine and as expected, but the money are not going out from the PayPal account which is used for the payment. Money is not going out from the credit card either. And of course money is not received by the account used for receiving.

Here's the code that generates the payment:

```
# Configure SDK.
paypalrestsdk.configure({
    'mode': settings.PAYPAL_MODE, # This one is set to 'live'.
    'client_id': settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': settings.PAYPAL_SECRET,
})

# Create a payment.
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": '...', # Here's the return URL.
        "cancel_url": '...', # Here's the cancel URL.
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "Invoice Payment #1",
                "sku": "item",
                "price": "1.00", # This is set to 1 for testing only.
                "currency": "AUD",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "total": "1.00", # Same as above.
            "currency": "AUD"
        },
        "description": "Invoice Payment #1"
    }]
})

# Get the payment URL if successful.
if payment.create():
    for link in payment.links:
        if link.method == "REDIRECT":
            redirect_url = str(link.href)
            "..."
            # Pass this variable to the HTML template context.
else:
    "..."
    # Handle the error.
```

So, I get the `redirect_url` pass it to the user. User initiates the payment. Payment is handled correctly but the money are not transferred or received.

Am I doing something wrong?

PS: here's a similar question I've just found — “[Paypal App does not receive money via REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201434/paypal-app-does-not-receive-money-via-rest)”.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

After PayPal redirects you back to your redirect url, you have “paymentId” and “PayerID” in your GET or POST parameters.

After that you use them to get the successful payment.

```
payment_id = request.GET.get('paymentId', None) or request.POST.get('paymentId', None)
payer_id = request.GET.get('PayerID', None) or request.POST.get('PayerID', None)
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(payment_id)
```

Then you need to execute the payment.

```
payment_response = payment.execute({'payer_id': payer_id})
```

And then if payment was executed successfully, do the rest of the stuff you need:

```
if payment_response:
    # Payment successful.
    ...
else:
    # Something went wrong.
    ...
```